# PHPMailer : how to set Content-Type to multipart/alternative

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm sending e-mails with phpmailer but the messages comes with Content-Type: text/html in the header.  how can I change it to multipart/alternative?

it should be something like  $mail->

my config is:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->setFrom('mail@mail.com', 'name');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                
$mail->CharSet = "ISO-8859-1";
$mail->XMailer = ' ';
```

Answer (score 3):

PHPMailer deals with this for you automatically. PHPMailer doesn't allow building arbitrary MIME structures, but it has a whole bunch of presets covering common scenarios. For example, to build a dual-format HTML & plain text message, just do this:

```
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->Body = "<strong>HTML content</strong>";
$mail->AltBody = "plain text content";
```

That will produce a message with a multipart/alternative MIME structure.